# Obtain output in REXX from DB2 Command

Tags: db2, mainframe, zos, rexx

I would like to use Rexx capture the output from the following commands:

```
QUEUE "-DIS DATABASE(*) SPACENAM(*) RESTRICT(CHKP,COPY)"
QUEUE "END"                                             
ADDRESS TSO "DSN SYSTEM(DB2D)"
```

Is there any way to obtain the name of tables output by the above commands  that are displayed into a variable or some other construct so the data can be manipulated programmatically?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OUTTRAP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ikja300/outtrap.htm) function should trap output from the DSN command. OUTTRAP is designed to **TRAP** the **OUT**put of most TSO commands. Output is placed in a variable (normally a stem variable) that you supply. (Certain TSO commands cannot be trapped; this is discussed elsewhere in the *TSO/E REXX Reference*.)

Taking your code as supplied above, we can cobble together this:

```
ORC = OUTTRAP('O.')             /* preserve prior setting of OUTTRAP */
QUEUE "-DIS DATABASE(*) SPACENAM(*) RESTRICT(CHKP,COPY)"
QUEUE "END"                                             
ADDRESS TSO "DSN SYSTEM(DB2D)"
CALL OUTTRAP ORC                /* restore OUTTRAP setting */
DO #O = 1 TO O.0                /* The 0 entry by convention has the number of records */
  /* You can PARSE, analyze, or do whatever here */
  SAY "O."'#O "='"O.#O"'"         /* example */
END #O                          /* end the loop */
```

OUTTRAP is a very powerful function when writing scripts in TSO/E REXX.